# how do i create a tar archive with fake "the f# way"

Tags: build, f#, build-automation, tar, f#-fake

i'm completely new to f# and fake, so excuse my horrible approach of creating a tar archive like

```
ArchiveHelper.Tar.CompressDir false (FileSystemHelper.directoryInfo "foo") (FileSystemHelper.fileInfo "bar.tar")
```

how would i write this in a more "functional" style?
i tried using a pipe but failed in doing so because `CompressDir`expects 3 parameters and i couldn't figure out how to use 2 named parameters and get the missing third from the other function.

thanks!

Comment: Unless you are using CompressDir multiple times in a function I would leave it the way you have it. If you do want to use pipelining then take a look at `||>` and `|||>` in [Symbol and Operator Reference (F#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233228.aspx). I don't use FAKE so I can't comment on that part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are using CompressDir multiple times in a function I would leave it the way you have it.

If you do want to use pipelining then take a look at `||>` and `|||>` in [Symbol and Operator Reference (F#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233228.aspx).

I don't use FAKE so I can't comment on that part.

Comment: awesome! just what i wanted. each day i like f# better :D